# What does "/factory,{CLSID 75*4b} -embedding" do?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer

Can someone explain me the following explorer CLI :

```
C:\windows\explorer.exe /factory,{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b} -Embedding
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`{75DFF2B7-6936-4C06-A8BB-676A7B00B24B} CLSID_SeparateMultipleProcessExplorerHost`

This just starts a separated `Explorer.exe`, so if one crashes the other stays alive. :-)

Comment: I do not have Launch folder windows in a separate process box checked

Comment: @iceman: You asked me to explain, you have your answer. Something else might cause this, but that's another question...

Comment: Is there a list of all of those GUID codes that includes that one?

Comment: @barlop: Yes, [the registry](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/5638f5cd-e7c9-4cc6-b584-11c723f507cc/2011-02-16_1409.png). :-)

Comment: By the way, on my machine I have {ceff45ee-c862-41de-aee2-a022c81eda92} CLSID_SeparateSingleProcessExplorerHost

Comment: @Lorenzo: That's standard, my answer suggests to take the Multiple version.

Comment: @iceman This is because something spawned that window for you by creating explorer.exe process with argument that is folder to open!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more in Tom's answer. When using IDM, when you press open folder button on Internet Download Manager's download complete dialog box, it will open a new explorer instance with similar command.

You might be doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

This separate processes are created because something spawned explorer.exe process with argument that is folder to open.

```
explorer.exe C:\test
```

No matter where you type this - in CMD, Run dialog of Task Manager. I even created explorer.exe process via `CreateProcess` API function from C++ code, and it still spawned it with the parent process of:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch -p
```

Instead of using my program as parent process (as happens with every other process you create). However, if I kill `explorer.exe` and then didn't supply `CreateProcess` with and command line arguments, it opened shell as with my program as parent, as expected. If you type `explorer.exe` in CMD to launch it after killing, it will have this parent:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p -s Schedule
```

Very peculiar behaviour from Windows, very confusing, indeed.

Update: I made some more experiments with the API and here is what I found out.

Using API function [ShellExecuteA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) you can actually open Explorer folder without creating separate `/factory,{CLSID}` process! Like this:

```
// Let The Shell do all the hard work =========================================================
HINSTANCE res = ShellExecuteA(
    NULL,           //  [I|O]  Handle to parent window that will show error or UI messages
    "explore",      //  [I|O]  Verb string -> open|edit|explore|find|open|print|runas|NULL(def)
    "C:\\",         //    [I]  File or object that the verb is beeing executed on
    NULL,           //  [I|O]  Cmd arguments to pass to the file, if it is exe file
    NULL,           //  [I|O]  Default working directory of the action NULL -> current dir
    SW_SHOWNORMAL); //    [I]  Parameter that sets default nCmdShow status of the window
// ============================================================================================
```

Alternatively, you can use `open` verb in-place of `explore` with the same result. However, doing it like this:

```
// Let The Shell do all the hard work =========================================================
HINSTANCE res = ShellExecuteA(
    NULL,           //  [I|O]  Handle to parent window that will show error or UI messages
    "open",         //  [I|O]  Verb string -> open|edit|explore|find|open|print|runas|NULL(def)
    "explorer.exe", //    [I]  File or object that the verb is beeing executed on
    "C:\\",         //  [I|O]  Cmd arguments to pass to the file, if it is exe file
    NULL,           //  [I|O]  Default working directory of the action NULL -> current dir
    SW_SHOWNORMAL); //    [I]  Parameter that sets default nCmdShow status of the window
// ============================================================================================
```

Results in same behaviour as calling `CreateProcess` with path argument. This suggests that if you launch Explorer from CMD, the latter uses `ShellExecute` with same parameters, internally.